# Error: unexpected input in "fit<-glm(Y1 ∼"

Tags: logistic-regression, categorical-data

```
Y1<- recode(Prostate_Cancer$Y,"8=1;c(6,7)=0")
X1 <- Prostate_Cancer$X1
X2 <- Prostate_Cancer$X2
X3 <- Prostate_Cancer$X3
X4 <- Prostate_Cancer$X4
X5 <- Prostate_Cancer$X5
X6 <- Prostate_Cancer$X6
X7 <- Prostate_Cancer$X7

fit<-glm(Y1 ∼ X1+X2+X3+X4+X5+X6+X7  , family=binomial , data=Prostate_Cancer)
```

I am getting below error:
Error: unexpected input in "fit<-glm(Y1 ∼"